# PHP API for Baidu?

Tags: javascript, php, api, analytics

Has anyone tried to integrate Baidu Tongji in their app? We have an app specifically for China and we'd like to manually log custom events in Tongji via their API. The problem is the one available is Javascript only and we need PHP because the events occur in the back-end. I'm wondering if there's a PHP version of their API?

Comment: Javascript api's are most of the time json apis. Why can't you do the json calls from php yourself (by using curl)? Or maybe you can bring the events to the webpage and sent them to Baidu using javascript?

Comment: @Veda Unfortunately, the api is exactly the same as google analytics. You have to embed a javascript code in HTML DOM before you can call the API.